# gethostbyaddr function is too slow (Perl socket programming)

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to run the example in this website
[tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_socket.htm)

But it's very slow. I thought it had something to do with buffering the response but changing print for syswrite did nothing so I added some debugging messages and found out that the function gethostbyaddr takes around 10 seconds to resolve.

I know there are other modules for socket programming but I was wondering if this problem is common.

I am running everything on localhost and I am using a mac

Comment: `gethostbyaddr` could run several seconds, because it has to make DNS request

Comment: How long does this command line take? `perl -MSocket -E'say gethostbyaddr(inet_aton("212.58.246.104"), AF_INET)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it can be slow. It contacts other machines to lookup a DNS entry. (Specifically, looking up the host name for address `w.x.y.z` results in a DNS lookup for the `PTR` record associated with `z.y.x.w.in-addr.arpa`.) If the authoritative DNS server is unresponsive, your machine is basically waiting for a response that will never come until your machine has decided it has waited long enough.

If you find `gethostbyaddr` too slow, don't use it. Just work with the IP address. It's not like `gethostbyaddr` is all that useful. `216.58.219.46` has names `lax17s04-in-f14.1e100.net` and `lax17s04-in-f46.1e100.net`, but you know it better as `google.com`. And then there's `209.85.250.97` for which `gethostbyaddr` returns no names, no matter how many domain names resolve to `209.85.250.97`.